# How to do multi-objective optimization using neural networks?

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have five decision variables, each having a specific range. I need to find a combination of these variables so as to maximize one of my objectives while minimizing the other at the same time. I have prepared a datasheet of randomly generated variables with respective values of the 2 objective functions. Please suggest me how to approach the solution using neural networks.

My objective function involves thermodynamic calculations. If interested you can have a look at the objective functions here :

Comment: data set: https://github.com/shroomer47/NSGA2/blob/master/dataset.xlsx

Comment: objective functions: https://github.com/shroomer47/NSGA2/blob/master/evaluate_objective.m

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then [edit] your question so your clarifications aren't buried in the comments.  Please format your code in the question rather just giving links to files.  See also [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is your question regarding Python or Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods, but the easiest way is "linear scalarization".
You can add objectives to make single objective.
While doing this, you can weight objectives considering priority.
(Making linear combination of multiple objectives)

See examples:
Variational AE loss (regularization loss + reconstruction loss)
Associative DA loss (classification loss + walker loss + visit loss)

Comment: I went through scalarization methods, and I want to compare results from e- constraint and weighted sum method, both. 
I still have one doubt, while doing e-constraint, I make separate networks for each objective + constraints. Then while optimizing each objective, say obj 2, how do I add other objectives and the constraints in that network?? 
If I'm not clear, I want to ask how do we implement the e-constraint method using neural networks? Can you explain this using a short example? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, I never used e-constraint method. I know there are some benefits using that, but I prefer scalarization method with hard weighting.
To response your comment, I've searched some papers, but still don't know how to implement.
Usually, for gradient descent with constraints, I use Lagrange multiplier method. But people don't seem to use it for e-constraint.
(They say computation of e-constraint is less than that of linear scalarization...but when we use Lagrange multiplier, computation will not be reduced).
Sorry for my lack of knowledge.